# Backendless - should i subscribe to a channel from service?

Tags: java, android, channel, backendless

In Backendless, there is a method from which I can subscribe to a channel and listen for incoming messages.

```
 Backendless.Messaging.subscribe(
                channelName, //some random name
                500,         //500 ms interval for polling
                new AsyncCallback<List<com.backendless.messaging.Message>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleResponse(List<com.backendless.messaging.Message> messages) {
                        System.out.println("message received on your channel");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {

                    }
                },
                new AsyncCallback<Subscription>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleResponse(Subscription subscription) {
                        System.out.println("You subscribed to channel" + subscription.getChannelName() + " succssesfuly");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {
                        System.out.println("Error: " + backendlessFault.getMessage());
                    }
                }
        );
```

If it subscribes from the MainActivity, and data was sent while the app is in another Activity, how can it grab the data from the response (the List in the first handleResponse method) and use it in other activities?
Should I use a service? Should I bind activities to this service with the listener?

Or is there any less complicated way to accomplish my need?

In the very near future i want this listener to work when the app is in the background and show a notification to a user.

Answer (score 0):

Backendless uses two types of Messaging, see [Publish-Subscribe Messaging & Push Notifications](https://backendless.com/documentation/messaging/android/messaging_overview.htm). The first one is implemented using the listener you used above. The second one uses a service. please refer to the docs, although they are not very good at all they do provide the necessary information.